# MYSQL Stored Procedures If statement Problem

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working with Mysql 5.1.28-rc on freebsd. I've just decided to use stored procedures in MYSQL and created a test procedure as below:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test( IN test VARCHAR(22) )
BEGIN
 DECLARE count INT(11);
 SET count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE test_column = test );
 SELECT count;
 IF count = 0 THEN
  SET count = 1;
 ELSE
  SET count = 2;
 ENDIF;
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

This procedure works well without IF statement in it , but with the if statement it gives, 
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
END'`

How can I solve this issue? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ENDIF` requires a space in MySQL doesn't it? i.e. `END IF`

Comment: holy cow ,  how could I miss that :)

Comment: It's nigh on impossible to spot typos in your own code, don't worry. Let's hear it for pair programming or, if you can't do that, SO... :D

Answer (score 5):

Just need space in `end if` in the stored procedure

Comment: Can you justify your answer? E.g. with a link to the documentation?

Comment: Justification? mona just copied the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Should not use variables like count or something. So please find the solution for this-

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN test VARCHAR(22) )
BEGIN
 DECLARE var_count INT;
 SET var_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE test.textfield = test);
 IF var_count = 0 THEN
  SET var_count = 1;
 ELSE SET var_count = 2;
 END IF;
 SELECT var_count;
END $$
```